# Django REST API AttributeError - The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `list` instance

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

We are trying to build Django Rest API functions for an existing Django Website. This website uses Django 3.1, MySQL 8.0 and Python 3.7. Further I am New to Django REST Api. Thus, need help with a common issue most of you may have faced in the past. Details below -

I am getting the following error message -

*AttributeError at /analysisapis/constituents
Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `strings` on serializer `ConstituentNameLists`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `list` instance.
Original exception text was: 'list' object has no attribute 'strings'.*

**My Model is as follows -**

Note -  This is common Model used from Django Website as well.

```
from django.db import models, connection
from django.urls import reverse

from . import queries as queries

# Create your models here.
class ISMASymbol(models.Manager):
    '''
    Used to Manage the Symbol
    '''
    def __init__(self):
        '''
        Initialize the Class instance
        '''
        self.symbol = 'NIFTY50'
        self.tablename = 'NIFTY50'
        self.exists = 2
        self.message = 'NIFTY50 exists.'
        self.close = 0
        self.change = 0
        self.returns = 0
        self.band = 0
        self.upperband = 0
        self.lowerband = 0
        self.lotsize = {0:0, 1:0, 2:0}
        self.stepvalue = 0
        self.weekly_expiry = True
        self.weekly_future = False
        self.isIndex = True
        self.cashstocks = []
        self.derivativestocks = []
        self.indexlist = []
        self.companyname = 'NIFTY 50'
        self.has_fno = True
        
    SOME ADDITIONAL FUNCTIONS
    
    def get_symbol_list(self):
        '''
        Creates a Symbol List for all Cash and Derivatives
        Used to Create Sitemap
        '''
        symbol_query = queries.symbol_list
        derivative_query = queries.derivative_list
        index_query = queries.index_list
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            # All Stock List
            cursor.execute(symbol_query)
            for item in cursor.fetchall():
                self.cashstocks.append(item[0])
            # Derivative List
            cursor.execute(derivative_query)
            for item in cursor.fetchall():
                self.derivativestocks.append(item[0])
            # Index List
            cursor.execute(index_query)
            for item in cursor.fetchall():
                self.indexlist.append(item[0])
            cursor.close()

    def get_cash_stocks(self):
        '''
        Returns all stocks listed on NSE
        '''
        return self.cashstocks

    def get_derivative_stocks(self):        
        '''
        Returns all derivative stocks listed on NSE
        '''
        return self.derivativestocks

    class Meta:
        proxy = True
```

**My Common function from Business Layer -**

Note -  This common function is called Django Website as well.

```
def get_constituents(indexname):
    '''
    Returns the Constituent details based on Index details
    '''
    constituents = None
    # Check for Index and accordingly populating Symbol List
    if (indexname == 'ALLSTOCKS'):
        constituents = symbol.get_cash_stocks()
    elif (indexname == 'DERIVATIVESONLY'):
        constituents = symbol.get_derivative_stocks()
    else:
        indexstocklist = get_index_constituents(indexname)
        constituents = indexstocklist
    return constituents
```

**My API View used to return just the list -**

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from analysis.business import get_constituents
from .serializers import ConstituentNameLists

class ConstituentList(APIView):
    '''
    Returns the List of Constituents
    '''
    def get(self, request, indexname='ALLSTOCKS'):
        '''
        Returns the Constituent List
        '''
        # Capturing Inputs in Appropriate Cases
        indexname = indexname.upper()
        constituents = get_constituents(indexname=indexname)
        print(constituents)
        serializer = ConstituentNameLists(constituents)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

**My Serializer for the list -**

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class ConstituentNameLists(serializers.Serializer):
    '''
    Returns Index Constituents
    '''
    strings = serializers.ListField(
        child = serializers.CharField(max_length=100)
    )
```

And the list that I am Trying to Serialize which is generating the above error -

> ['NIFTYINFRA', 'NIFTYALPHA50', 'NIFTYPHARMA', 'NIFTY50TR2XLEV','NIFTYMIDCAP100', 'NIFTYCPSE', NIFTY50TR1XINV', 'NIFTYCONSUMPTION','NIFTY50PR1XINV', 'INDIAVIX']

Please help me resolve this issue.

Comment: I think you might need to provide a list of objects which has `strings` attribute containing the data to be passed back as suggested by the exception `Original exception text was: 'list' object has no attribute 'strings'.`

Answer (score 0):

One does not need to serialize the List of Strings which are coming as an output since they are native python data types. So the Code in the View needs to to as follows -

```
class ConstituentList(APIView):
    def get(self, request, indexname='ALLSTOCKS'):
        # Capturing Inputs in Appropriate Cases
        indexname = indexname.upper()
        constituents = get_constituents(indexname=indexname)
        return Response(constituents)
```

Thus, No Serailization needed for Native datatypes.